# Usage of 'Runtime.getRuntime()' inside / outside a loop

Tags: java, runtime, cpu, cpu-usage, runtime.exec

What is the difference between the following codes?
Does this impact either the CPU or memory when executing the 'exec' method?

```
Code #1
{
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
while(true) {
Process pr = runtime.exec("SOME COMMAND HERE");
}
}

Code #2
{
while(true) {
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("SOME COMMAND HERE");
}
}
```

I just want to know if there is much difference in these 2 approaches and in what areas do they differ?

Thanks

Comment: The first form (caching the result value) will never be slower, no matter which method you're talking about. It depends on the method how much benefit you get, from imperceptible to massive, and if you want to know, you should benchmark it. `getRuntime` specifically looks like it doesn't do much other than returning a singleton, but you shouldn't rely on it. If in doubt, cache the value.

Comment: Note:  starting processes without waiting for them to finish will quickly overwhelm your system.

Comment: @Amadan, when we speak of getRuntime(), does this not open up filehandles within the JRE, and if too many were spawned, will most likely eat up memory causing errors like 'Cannot allocate memory exception'??

Comment: @VGR, thanks for the reminder and yes I am well aware of that. :)

Comment: I can say that [OpenJDK 10 `Runtime.getRuntime`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/777356696811/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Runtime.java#l67) simply returns a singleton variable. I can't say what Oracle Java does, I can't say what Java's next version will do, or what some other implementation does.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the first approach will save a few nanoseconds, but compared to the time of an `exec`, it's negligible.
I wouldn't bother.